# Application icon does not change after update

Tags: ios, app-store

After updating application on the app store we see responses from our users that on some devices spring board icon did not change.

It was update which has been written completely from scratch so there wasn't any old image files in project.

I can't find any dependencies. Icon is just randomly changing or not on devices.

What I should do to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!)

Comment: Did you try to delete your new app icon from xcassets?(I guess you did :)
I got a bug once, where I had multiple images for icons on top of each other...

Also, try to search for "icon" in your project to make sure, there isn't any file (except your new one) called like that as it will be automatically used as app icon

Answer (score 1):

I already got this problem.

Check your *myApp-info.plist* so your icons correspond really to your new files. (If needed, delete all and rewrite all).

[image: myApp-info.plist icons details]

Comment: I got this category empty. I'm using Images.xcassets for icons.